# which is a better practice - global var or singleton?

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, singleton

I'm confused - which approach is best in sharing data between Scenes in a Cocos2d project.
The data consists of a set of integer variables that are not constant. These should be accessible throughout all the Scenes.

As I looked through the Web for solution, I found two basic approaches:
1) Singleton
2) A header file with global variables declaration

My question goes: which (and WHY) is better in my specific case?

The nearest topic I found is-  [What is better: Global string or singleton?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/437122/what-is-better-global-string-or-singleton)  but it doesn't really help.

Comment: you have to use 1st approach  for multiple int  and create  `NSObject` type class and create all int property in that and create that class object in app delegate and this object access with whole your app using shared delegate.

Comment: thank you for your comment! I understand your point. Would you please take the time to make a full answer describing WHY this approach is better? Thanks!

Comment: i can't give you a description b'coz i can't explain this as a theory and i was just giving suggestion b'coz if i need to use this kind of requirement than i'm coding like this.

Comment: thank you. I also think that singleton is somewhat a smarter way but a little less straight forward. ButI decided to ask as I don't know the inner part of how the data is managed within the project. Anyway thank you for you comment!